# Fix the Sequence of Zorder Parameters in Matplotlib 3D plotting of LineCollections

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble with a 3D matplotlib plot showing subsequent 2D line profiles with time. The plot ends up exactly how I want it to look except that the 2D profiles are overlapping each other in the wrong order, which confuses anyone who views the plot. The profiles are being plotted correctly along the time axis, but it's almost like they are added to the plot in the opposite order. I think has something to do with the "zorder" term in matplotlib, but I've been unsuccessful in fixing this problem. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

profiles = []
times = []

index = 0

for item in intensities:
    integrated_profile = integrate(item)
    profiles.append(list(zip(x_coordinates, integrated_profile)))
    
    timestamps = int(index+1)
    times.append(timestamps)

    index += 1

profiles = np.array(profiles)
times = np.array(times)


profile_collection = LineCollection(profiles, colors=color_list) #color_list not shown here

fig = plt.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(18,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d',proj_type='ortho')
ax.add_collection3d(profile_collection, zs=times, zdir='y')

# I deleted a lot more lines of code which are just formatting the plot
```

[image: Here is the plot]

Comment: Are the time series numbers on the time axis in a proprietary format of 'matplotlib'? If so, you need to convert it. If so, you need to convert it. [date2num](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. This is actually an easier way to create this type of plot. Instead of storing the 2D profiles in a collection, I just looped through and added them individually to the 3D plot. A collection has on fixed zorder value, so you cannot change what I was wanting to change. When you loop through and plot each 2D profile individually, you can set the zorder parameter according to how you want it. Here's what I did:

```
profiles = []
times = []

index = 0

for item in intensities:
    integrated_profile = integrate(item)
    profiles.append(integrated_profile)
    
    timestamps = int(index+1)
    times.append(timestamps)

    index += 1

profiles = np.array(profiles)
times = np.array(times)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(18,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d',proj_type='ortho')

index2 = 0
for i in profiles:
    ax.plot(x_coordinates, profiles[index2], zs=times[index2], zdir='y', 
            zorder=(len(profiles) - index2), color=next(colors))
    index2 += 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is another pretty quick way to fix the non-intuitive overlapping of the single lines in 3D. It seems like matplotlib is just plotting the single curves beginning at the start of the input towards its end. In case of data that is sorted in ascending order, e.g. chronologically like in the example of the question, this tends to plot the "nearest" curve first. Perspectively, the next curve that would be farther away should appear behind the first, but matplotlib plots any new curve just on top of anything else. Curves located "farther" away, but overlapping nearer curves messes up the perspective.

**Workaround:** Sort the data in a way that the plotting starts in the background and moves to the foreground. In the example that would mean a descending order, i.e. last time stamp first. Then, perspective and overlapping order are coherent. The last curve will be the "nearest" one which overlaps all other curves.

In the example of the question, this could be achieved by reversing the columns of the `profiles` 2d-array and reversing the `time` array:

```
profiles = np.array(profiles)
times    = np.array(times)

profiles = profiles[:, ::-1]    # Reverse columns of a 2d-array
times    = [::-1]               # Invert 1d-array
```

Alternatively, I assume, swapping the time axis instead of re-ordering the data might also do the trick, but I haven't tested that. Anyway, that might not be desired.